# Curl shows output when assigning to a variable

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl with php to run a background job like that:

```
function RunBackground($script)
{
$cs=curl_init();

curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);       
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, $script);
$response = curl_exec($cs);

curl_close($cs);
}

RunBackground("script.php?some=variables");
```

However I have some output where everything should be in $response no ??
Thanks

Comment: No, it shouldn't, by default cURL will just spill the output to whatever it's calling it. You need to `curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)` and assign it to a variable. Read more on cURL [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`

```
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If this option is set, the result is returned and can be stored in your variable. Otherwise `curl_exec` returns `true` on success and `false` on error.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

So your full example should be

```
function RunBackground($script)
{
    $cs=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);       
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, $script);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($cs);

    curl_close($cs);
}

RunBackground("script.php?some=variables");
```